# Issue Using JSON for lenth more than 11000 chars in JSON_VALUE in oracle 12c

Tags: sql, json, oracle, plsql, oracle12c

I am running the following code on Oracle 12c :

```
DECLARE
       l_json clob;
       l_var varchar2(90);
       l_query clob;
       mypath clob;
       l_path_value varchar2(100);
BEGIN
    SELECT json_column into l_json from my_table;
    SELECT path_column into l_path_value from my_table;  -- this returns 'watchers'
    mypath := '$.second."'||l_path_value||'"'; -- $.second."watchers"
    l_query := 'select json_value('''||l_json||''', '''||mypath||''' ERROR ON ERROR)  from dual';
    execute Immediate l_query into l_var;
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('var: '||l_var);
END;
```

> After running this, i get the result as: 
>   Error report -
>   ORA-40441: JSON syntax error
>   ORA-06512: at line 12
>   40441. 00000 -  "JSON syntax error"
>   *Cause:    The provided JavaScript Object Notation (JSON) data had invalid
>              syntax and could not be parsed.
>   *Action:   Provide JSON data with the correct syntax.

I am expecting result as:

> var: 0

So is there a problem with length of the JSON passed?

My json looks like :

```
  {
"first": {
    "private": false,
    "html_url": "https://github.com/mralexgray/Alfred-Google-Translate",
    "description": "Extension for Alfred that will do a Google translate for you",
    "fork": true,
    "url": "https://api.github.com/repos/mralexgray/Alfred-Google-Translate",
    "forks_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/mralexgray/Alfred-Google-Translate/forks",
    "keys_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/mralexgray/Alfred-Google-Translate/keys{/key_id}",
    "collaborators_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/mralexgray/Alfred-Google-Translate/collaborators{/collaborator}",
    "teams_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/mralexgray/Alfred-Google-Translate/teams",
    "hooks_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/mralexgray/Alfred-Google-Translate/hooks",
    "issue_events_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/mralexgray/Alfred-Google-Translate/issues/events{/number}",
    "events_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/mralexgray/Alfred-Google-Translate/events",
    "assignees_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/mralexgray/Alfred-Google-Translate/assignees{/user}",
    "branches_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/mralexgray/Alfred-Google-Translate/branches{/branch}",
    "tags_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/mralexgray/Alfred-Google-Translate/tags",
    "blobs_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/mralexgray/Alfred-Google-Translate/git/blobs{/sha}",
    "git_tags_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/mralexgray/Alfred-Google-Translate/git/tags{/sha}",
    "git_refs_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/mralexgray/Alfred-Google-Translate/git/refs{/sha}",
    "trees_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/mralexgray/Alfred-Google-Translate/git/trees{/sha}",
    "statuses_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/mralexgray/Alfred-Google-Translate/statuses/{sha}",
    "languages_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/mralexgray/Alfred-Google-Translate/languages",
    "stargazers_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/mralexgray/Alfred-Google-Translate/stargazers",
    "contributors_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/mralexgray/Alfred-Google-Translate/contributors",
    "subscribers_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/mralexgray/Alfred-Google-Translate/subscribers",
    "subscription_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/mralexgray/Alfred-Google-Translate/subscription",
    "commits_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/mralexgray/Alfred-Google-Translate/commits{/sha}",
    "git_commits_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/mralexgray/Alfred-Google-Translate/git/commits{/sha}",
    "comments_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/mralexgray/Alfred-Google-Translate/comments{/number}",
    "issue_comment_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/mralexgray/Alfred-Google-Translate/issues/comments{/number}",
    "contents_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/mralexgray/Alfred-Google-Translate/contents/{+path}",
    "compare_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/mralexgray/Alfred-Google-Translate/compare/{base}...{head}",
    "merges_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/mralexgray/Alfred-Google-Translate/merges",
    "archive_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/mralexgray/Alfred-Google-Translate/{archive_format}{/ref}",
    "downloads_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/mralexgray/Alfred-Google-Translate/downloads",
    "issues_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/mralexgray/Alfred-Google-Translate/issues{/number}",
    "pulls_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/mralexgray/Alfred-Google-Translate/pulls{/number}",
    "milestones_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/mralexgray/Alfred-Google-Translate/milestones{/number}",
    "notifications_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/mralexgray/Alfred-Google-Translate/notifications{?since,all,participating}",
    "labels_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/mralexgray/Alfred-Google-Translate/labels{/name}",
    "releases_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/mralexgray/Alfred-Google-Translate/releases{/id}",
    "deployments_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/mralexgray/Alfred-Google-Translate/deployments",
    "created_at": "2013-06-04T10:45:10Z",
    "updated_at": "2013-06-04T10:45:10Z",
    "pushed_at": "2013-01-12T19:39:03Z",
    "git_url": "git://github.com/mralexgray/Alfred-Google-Translate.git",
    "ssh_url": "git@github.com:mralexgray/Alfred-Google-Translate.git",
    "clone_url": "https://github.com/mralexgray/Alfred-Google-Translate.git",
    "svn_url": "https://github.com/mralexgray/Alfred-Google-Translate",
    "homepage": null,
    "size": 103,
    "stargazers_count": 0,
    "watchers_count": 0,
    "language": "Shell",
    "has_issues": false,
    "has_downloads": true,
    "has_wiki": true,
    "has_pages": false,
    "forks_count": 0,
    "mirror_url": null,
    "open_issues_count": 0,
    "forks": 0,
    "open_issues": 0,
    "watchers": 0,
    "default_branch": "master"
},
"second": {
    "private": false,
    "html_url": "https://github.com/mralexgray/Alfred-Google-Translate",
    "description": "Extension for Alfred that will do a Google translate for you",
    "fork": true,
    "url": "https://api.github.com/repos/mralexgray/Alfred-Google-Translate",
    "forks_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/mralexgray/Alfred-Google-Translate/forks",
    "keys_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/mralexgray/Alfred-Google-Translate/keys{/key_id}",
    "collaborators_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/mralexgray/Alfred-Google-Translate/collaborators{/collaborator}",
    "teams_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/mralexgray/Alfred-Google-Translate/teams",
    "hooks_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/mralexgray/Alfred-Google-Translate/hooks",
    "issue_events_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/mralexgray/Alfred-Google-Translate/issues/events{/number}",
    "events_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/mralexgray/Alfred-Google-Translate/events",
    "assignees_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/mralexgray/Alfred-Google-Translate/assignees{/user}",
    "branches_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/mralexgray/Alfred-Google-Translate/branches{/branch}",
    "tags_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/mralexgray/Alfred-Google-Translate/tags",
    "blobs_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/mralexgray/Alfred-Google-Translate/git/blobs{/sha}",
    "git_tags_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/mralexgray/Alfred-Google-Translate/git/tags{/sha}",
    "git_refs_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/mralexgray/Alfred-Google-Translate/git/refs{/sha}",
    "trees_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/mralexgray/Alfred-Google-Translate/git/trees{/sha}",
    "statuses_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/mralexgray/Alfred-Google-Translate/statuses/{sha}",
    "languages_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/mralexgray/Alfred-Google-Translate/languages",
    "stargazers_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/mralexgray/Alfred-Google-Translate/stargazers",
    "contributors_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/mralexgray/Alfred-Google-Translate/contributors",
    "subscribers_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/mralexgray/Alfred-Google-Translate/subscribers",
    "subscription_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/mralexgray/Alfred-Google-Translate/subscription",
    "commits_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/mralexgray/Alfred-Google-Translate/commits{/sha}",
    "git_commits_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/mralexgray/Alfred-Google-Translate/git/commits{/sha}",
    "comments_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/mralexgray/Alfred-Google-Translate/comments{/number}",
    "issue_comment_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/mralexgray/Alfred-Google-Translate/issues/comments{/number}",
    "contents_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/mralexgray/Alfred-Google-Translate/contents/{+path}",
    "compare_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/mralexgray/Alfred-Google-Translate/compare/{base}...{head}",
    "merges_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/mralexgray/Alfred-Google-Translate/merges",
    "archive_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/mralexgray/Alfred-Google-Translate/{archive_format}{/ref}",
    "downloads_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/mralexgray/Alfred-Google-Translate/downloads",
    "issues_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/mralexgray/Alfred-Google-Translate/issues{/number}",
    "pulls_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/mralexgray/Alfred-Google-Translate/pulls{/number}",
    "milestones_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/mralexgray/Alfred-Google-Translate/milestones{/number}",
    "notifications_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/mralexgray/Alfred-Google-Translate/notifications{?since,all,participating}",
    "labels_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/mralexgray/Alfred-Google-Translate/labels{/name}",
    "releases_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/mralexgray/Alfred-Google-Translate/releases{/id}",
    "deployments_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/mralexgray/Alfred-Google-Translate/deployments",
    "created_at": "2013-06-04T10:45:10Z",
    "updated_at": "2013-06-04T10:45:10Z",
    "pushed_at": "2013-01-12T19:39:03Z",
    "git_url": "git://github.com/mralexgray/Alfred-Google-Translate.git",
    "ssh_url": "git@github.com:mralexgray/Alfred-Google-Translate.git",
    "clone_url": "https://github.com/mralexgray/Alfred-Google-Translate.git",
    "svn_url": "https://github.com/mralexgray/Alfred-Google-Translate",
    "homepage": null,
    "size": 103,
    "stargazers_count": 0,
    "watchers_count": 0,
    "language": "Shell",
    "has_issues": false,
    "has_downloads": true,
    "has_wiki": true,
    "has_pages": false,
    "forks_count": 0,
    "mirror_url": null,
    "open_issues_count": 0,
    "forks": 0,
    "open_issues": 0,
    "watchers": 0,
    "default_branch": "master"
   }
}
```

Comment: It looks like you've shown a made-up example, which might not be helpful. Without seeing your real JSON and path - or at least something that we can use to recreate the issue - a likely explanation is a typo or perhaps character confusion or a slight mistake in the structure. Or indeed what JoshMaag suggestd, but again that isn't shown by your example.

Comment: @AlexPoole, I have updated the real JSON and updated the JSON_VALUE query. I am getting exception that JSON syntax is incorrect, but i have validated the json syntax. it is correct. is there a problem because of the length of json? Please help.

Comment: What you've shown [works on Oracle's Live SQL](https://livesql.oracle.com/apex/livesql/s/ed2ddt004q6vwdx3uns56rt4k), both as a CLOB literal and with a CLOB column from a table. I would guess you have a control character or something else we can't see in your actual table value. (BTW, do you have an `is json` check constraint on that column?)

Comment: @AlexPoole, yes i have `is json` constraint on this column.

Comment: Then what you have stored should already be valid. I'm sure the size isn't actually an issue, but the example you have now is less than 10000 characters - so do you actually get the error with that exact value? Are there control characters, or multibyte characters, in your real data?

Comment: Also... which version and patch level are you on, and are you using compression (and multibyte characters)? Wondering if you're seeing bug 20577490, maybe.

Comment: @AlexPoole, I have found/re-produced the issue, it is because i am using Dynamic query using `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE`. I have updated the question with the exact query. My requirement is to make the json-path dynamically. Can you please have a look?

Comment: Also, it even breaks with JSON of 5000 characters with this(Dynamic query)

Comment: That also works fine for me. I'd bind the JSON value rather than converting it to a literal, but not sure what would mater - not with the text you've shown, anyway. Add `dbms_output.put_line(l_query);` to see if something is being corrupted - check the path, but also (more importantly, from the error) the converted JSON value.

Comment: @AlexPoole, " I'd bind the JSON value rather than converting it to a literal" can you show the code for this?

Comment: @AlexPoole, not sure how `:json` works. Please explain.

Comment: @AlexPoole, oh got it. it worked :)

Comment: @AlexPoole Thanks a ton.

Answer (score 0):

If your varchar2(90) is too small for the return value it may return null. See [JSON_value_on_error_clause](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions093.htm#CJAHDAFG) for a reference.

Comment: i have updated the question with real JSON and error trace. Please check.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure it will help - with the example you've shown it doesn't make any difference, and I'm not sure whether any control or multibyte characters in a different value might cause a problem - but I would bind the JSON value, rather than implicitly converting to a string and back:

```
l_query := 'select json_value(:json, '''||mypath||''' ERROR ON ERROR)  from dual';
execute Immediate l_query into l_var using l_json;
```